# Fastest way to get system uptime in Python in Linux

Tags: python, linux

I'm looking for a fast and lightweight way to read system uptime from a Python script. Is there a way to call the `sysinfo` Linux system call from Python?

So far I've found two other methods for measuring uptime, one that involves running an external processes and one that involves reading a file in `/proc`.

```
import subprocess

def uptime1():
    raw = subprocess.check_output('uptime').decode("utf8").replace(',', '')
    days = int(raw.split()[2])
    if 'min' in raw:
        hours = 0
        minutes = int(raw[4])
    else:
        hours, minutes = map(int,raw.split()[4].split(':'))
    totalsecs = ((days * 24 + hours) * 60 + minutes) * 60
    return totalsecs

def uptime2():  
    with open('/proc/uptime', 'r') as f:
        uptime_seconds = float(f.readline().split()[0])
        return uptime_seconds
```

When comparing the speed, the second method is around 50 times faster. Still, calling a system call directly should be yet another order of magnitude better.

```
>> import timeit
>> print(timeit.timeit('ut.uptime1()', setup="import uptimecalls as ut", number=1000))
1.7286969429987948
>> print(timeit.timeit('ut.uptime2()', setup="import uptimecalls as ut", number=1000))
0.03355383600865025
```

Comment: files in `/proc/` are not files... they are eventually hooked up to some other things allowing you to set/get different things. you can load `.so` files in python if you want to. but isn't 0.03s/1000times fast enough?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think you can get much faster than using `ctypes` to call `sysinfo()` but in my tests, its slower than /proc. Those linux system programmers seem to know what they are doing!

```
import ctypes
import struct

def uptime3():
    libc = ctypes.CDLL('libc.so.6')
    buf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(4096) # generous buffer to hold
                                            # struct sysinfo
    if libc.sysinfo(buf) != 0:
        print('failed')
        return -1

    uptime = struct.unpack_from('@l', buf.raw)[0]
    return uptime
```

Running your two tests plus mine on my slow laptop, I got:

```
>>> print(timeit.timeit('ut.uptime1()', setup="import uptimecalls as ut", number=1000))
5.284219555993332
>>> print(timeit.timeit('ut.uptime2()', setup="import uptimecalls as ut", number=1000))
0.1044210599939106
>>> print(timeit.timeit('ut.uptime3()', setup="import uptimecalls as ut", number=1000))
0.11733305400412064
```

**UPDATE**

Most of the time is spent pulling in `libc` and creating the buffer. If you plan to make the call repeatedly over time, then you can pull those steps out of the function and measure just the system call. In that case, this solution is the clear winner:

```
uptime1: 5.066633300986723
uptime2: 0.11561189399799332
uptime3: 0.007740753993857652
```

Comment: Indeed they do... Thanks. However, on a second thought, I believe this can be optimized by taking the first one or two lines out of the function call.

Comment: This is what I get with libs and buffer as global variables: uptime1: 1.8627383150014794
uptime2:  0.03709090399206616
uptime3: 0.0018650189886102453

Comment: But basically you answered my question by showing how to call C library functions from Python.

Comment: I put it into the `def` to factor in the cost of getting the `libc` reference. If you plan to call this multiple times in a single program, then pulling it out of the function to test the timing is legitimate. Retesting, I got `5.066633300986723, 0.11561189399799332, 0.007740753993857652`. Looks like we beat those slacker system programmers after all.

Answer (score 37):

This frankly seems like a much better solution:

```
def get_uptime():
    with open('/proc/uptime', 'r') as f:
        uptime_seconds = float(f.readline().split()[0])

    return uptime_seconds
```

It also has the added benefit of not requiring any additional modules.

Credits: [Source](http://planzero.org/blog/2012/01/26/system_uptime_in_python,_a_better_way)

Answer (score 29):

You can try installing `psutil` with:

```
pip install psutil
```

and then use the following fragment of code:

```
import psutil
import time


def seconds_elapsed():
    return time.time() - psutil.boot_time()


print(seconds_elapsed())
```

Comment: i would be very surprised that this can be significantly faster than approach 2: https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/psutil/_pslinux.py#L1255

Comment: Me too but maybe it's the fastest cross platform and portable solution even if the OP asks for linux

Comment: This answer is boring. It's much too simple! ... (joking) I want to say: Thank you for this nice answer.

Comment: Use psutil.boot_time() if running a more modern version of psutil.

Comment: Using system time for measuring elapsed time is bad practise. You can easilly end with negative uptime if the computer adjust system time by several minutes after boot.
There are also other systems with unrelayable system time where this can cause much more problems.

Answer (score 14):

### TL;DR

Simple, but not guaranteed to be uptime. Should represent uptime on Linux and Windows Vista+, python 3.3+

```py
time.monotonic()
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.monotonic

More correct linux specific, real equivalent to linux uptime, python 3.7+

```py
time.clock_gettime(time.CLOCK_BOOTTIME)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.clock_gettime
https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.CLOCK_BOOTTIME

---

Long answer

Nobody mention simple monotonic clock. POSIX specifies CLOCK_MONOTONIC to be monotonic clock **from unspecified time** but Linux specifies it to [start at boot](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/timekeeping.html)

On Linux, python uses `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` in `time.monotonic()`

So getting uptime can be as simple as calling

```py
import time
print(time.monotonic())
```

Fortunately, this will also work for many other platforms as uptime (e.g. on Windows, it uses `GetTickCount64`)

Problem with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is that it does not count deep sleep. So you can use CLOCK_BOOTTIME instead. This works on Linux kernel from 2.6.39 and python from  3.7. `/proc/uptime` uses `ktime_get_boottime` internally which is `CLOCK_BOOTTIME` time scale. So 1:1 replacement is this.

```py
import time
print(time.clock_gettime(time.CLOCK_BOOTTIME))
```

---

Just for comparison of the speed, it is also the fastest. `uptime1` does not work for me so testing only other variants

```py
import time
import ctypes
import struct
libc = ctypes.CDLL('libc.so.6')

def uptime2():  
    with open('/proc/uptime', 'r') as f:
        uptime_seconds = float(f.readline().split()[0])
        return uptime_seconds

def uptime3():
    buf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(128)
    if libc.sysinfo(buf) != 0:
        return None

    uptime = struct.unpack_from('@l', buf.raw)[0]
    return uptime

uptime4 = time.monotonic

uptime5 = lambda: time.clock_gettime(time.CLOCK_BOOTTIME)
```

```py
>>> print(timeit.timeit('ut.uptime2()', setup="import uptimecalls as ut", number=10000))
0.2356316399964271
>>> print(timeit.timeit('ut.uptime3()', setup="import uptimecalls as ut", number=10000))
0.05088816500210669
>>> print(timeit.timeit('ut.uptime4()', setup="import uptimecalls as ut", number=10000))
0.003676328000437934
>>> print(timeit.timeit('ut.uptime5()', setup="import uptimecalls as ut", number=10000))
0.012754358001984656
```

So it is also the fastest solution.

Answer (score 8):

Adding an **UP TO DATE** answer.

This may not be the fastest way. But this is should be the replacement for `psutil.boot_time()` since I couldn't find `boot_time` in latest versions of linux `psutil` lib.

Dependancy:

```
pip3 install uptime
```

Usage:

```
>>> from uptime import uptime
>>> uptime()
49170.129999999997
```

[More info](https://pythonhosted.org/uptime/)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the previous, this will get you the system uptime as a `datetime` object:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def uptime():
    with open("/proc/uptime", "rb") as f:
        seconds = float(f.readline().split(maxsplit=1)[0])
        return datetime.now() - timedelta(seconds=seconds))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import os
print(os.times()[4])
```

python 2

```
os.times()
Return a 5-tuple of floating point numbers indicating accumulated (processor or other) times, in seconds. The items are: user time, system time, children’s user time, children’s system time, and elapsed real time since a fixed point in the past, in that order. See the Unix manual page times(2) or the corresponding Windows Platform API documentation. On Windows, only the first two items are filled, the others are zero.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html
```

python 3

```
os.times()
Returns the current global process times. The return value is an object with five attributes:

user - user time

system - system time

children_user - user time of all child processes

children_system - system time of all child processes

elapsed - elapsed real time since a fixed point in the past

For backwards compatibility, this object also behaves like a five-tuple containing user, system, children_user, children_system, and elapsed in that order.

See the Unix manual page times(2) and times(3) manual page on Unix or the GetProcessTimes MSDN on Windows. On Windows, only user and system are known; the other attributes are zero.

Availability: Unix, Windows.

Changed in version 3.3: Return type changed from a tuple to a tuple-like object with named attributes.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html
```

Comment: You seem to be mixing prose and code formatting. Please use this info https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: `elapsed` does not represent uptime but rather `uptime + some fixed large random number`